# Generate stubs from contract repo by each consumer using gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle, spring-cloud-contract

Spring has provided a sample in maven that can generate the stub for each procducer service by placing a pom.xml in the respective directory.

[Link to example](http://cloud-samples.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tutorials/contracts_external.html#_setting_up_spring_cloud_contract_in_the_producer_contracts_config_file_inside_the_contracts_repo)

How do I do this with gradle with the file structure below and I only want to build the stub for api1 only?

```
src/
  main/
   resources/
     contracts/
       api1/
         consumer1/
           rest
         consumer2/
           rest
       api2/
         consumer1/
           rest
```

**Update**:
Just found out that I can specify the consumer name in @AutoConfigureStubRunner so now I just need to be able to generate the stub based on each API with gradle.

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(workOffline = true,
    ids = "com.example:beer-api-producer-with-stubs-per-consumer",
    stubsPerConsumer = true,
    consumerName = "bar-consumer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the jar task in Gradle. https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_with_restdocs/build.gradle You have an example of one here.

It's enough for you to modify the paths and it should work. Example below:

```
task stubsJar(type: Jar) {
    into("/") {
        include('**/*.groovy')
        from("${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/contracts")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it is working for me.  I thought the stub should have the mapping json at first, so I guess all I need is the groovy to start with stub-runner.

Comment: You need the groovy for messaging and to generate stubs. To use stub runner for http you need the json stubs. I didn't know what your requirement is.

Comment: This is the external contract repo scenario where the client can pull the contract repo and create a stub for the service they are using for integration testing until the finalize stub publish by the producer then client can repoint to it

Comment: So the stub jar is necessary but with the corresponding generated stubs. You'd have to run the gradle build with test skipping on a given folder of a producer or on the whole thing and set the plugin to process the contracts accordingly. In other words migrate this https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/beer_contracts to gradle

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do =(. Do you have any tips on migrating to gradle ?

Comment: You can file an issue in spring cloud contract to update the sample with this info

Comment: sounds good. Currently I did it with creating ext.property for the contractsDslDir and ask the consumer to key in the producer artifactid and a custom stubJar changing the base name to the artifactid